# Can't figure out the dateformat string for 9/30/11 2:58:49 PM EST?

Tags: java, date, date-format

9/30/11 2:58:49 PM EST

what is the Java date format for this??
something like "MM/dd/YY HH:MM:SS ???"

Comment: This is a question that has been asked already many times.  Try using google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you google it ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

An extract of this doc :

```
Date and Time Pattern   Result
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"  2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"  Wed, Jul 4, '01
"h:mm a"    12:08 PM
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"K:mm a, z" 0:08 PM, PDT
"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"  02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"    Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ" 010704120856-0700
```

So, you can try this :

```
"MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a z"
```

Comment: yea..i figured it out 5 minutes after i posted it..forgot to delete my question! :/ ...SORRY FOLKS.